# Why does Hibernate not find the default schema defined in application.properties?

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I am currently trying to configure my Spring Boot application so it can talk with my H2 database through Hibernate. As far as I know, the application manages to succesfully connect to the database but it is then unable to find the default database schema as defined in my application.properties file. I have already tried manually creating the database schema through RazorSQL but this did not work.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/dndmp;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.username=DNDMP
spring.datasource.password=tttt

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dndmp
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! So far, this seems to work. JDBC at least seems able to find the provided default schema but I still can't find my test data. When I do, I'll accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: Sadly, after further research I have come to the conclusion that setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` did not solve my problem. My application is still unable to find the `dndmp` schema.

Comment: can you please past the exception, or if possible can you put your code in github so it will easy for us to debug you code

Comment: Here is the link to my project. I've included the H2 database files as well.

https://bitbucket.org/Wouter-Dumoulin/d-d-multiplayer.git

Comment: also it successfully creating table

  ```drop table dndmp.creature_sheets if exists
2017-11-09 15:24:08.934 DEBUG 16440 --- [onPool-worker-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table dndmp.creature_sheets (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        alignment varchar(255),
        armor_class integer not null,
        hit_dice varchar(255),
        hit_dice_amount integer not null,
        creature_name varchar(255),
        creature_size varchar(255),
        creature_type varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )```

Comment: That may be correct, I tried a few other possible solutions since yesterday. If you check the database with RazorSQL for example, you'll notice that my application did not create any tables.

Comment: I have created some data and it's successfully inserting in db and fetch as well'